# Crear una etiqueta IMG de HTML con PHP

Tags: php

quiero crear una etiqueta `img` de **HTML** que cargue una imagen que reciba de la BD, estoy haciendo un `echo` de la siguiente manera :

```
<?php echo "<img class='card-img-top' src='../static/imagenes/$usuario['imagen_url']' alt='Card Image'>"; ?>
```

Pero me da el siguiente **error:**

> syntax error, unexpected ''

Answer (score 2, accepted):

tienes dos opciones, 
Opcion 1:

```
$imagen=$usuario['imagen_url'];
<?php echo "<img class='card-img-top' src='../static/imagenes/$usuario['imagen_url']' alt='Card Image'>"; ?>
```

Opcion 2 "escapar las comillas con \":

Answer (score -1):

Has probado cambiar las comillas simples por las dobles de esta manera?`<?php echo '<img class="card-img-top" src="../static/imagenes/$usuario["imagen_url"]" alt="Card Image">'; ?>`

Comment: Esto va a seguir dando error pues el problema no es comillas simples o dobles si no el uso erroneo de estas.